# How would I use printf() and a String array of inputed words to print out within a box of asterisks

Tags: java

In this format where 'Nivla' would be within a String List, and input is available to be formatted by the user.

```
************
*   Nivla  *
************
```

Also, the box would increase in size with the lines of the string array. E.g. ["Nivla is" , "not intelligent"];

```
**********************
*      Nivla is      *
*   not intelligent  *
**********************
```

Also, I'm having trouble centering the string around the center like above.

The code I'm current using is:

```
public void run() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> inputs = new ArrayList<>();
        String input;
        do {
            input = s.nextLine();
            inputs.add(input);
        } while(!input.equals(""));
        printBox(inputs);
    }

    public void printBox(ArrayList inputs) {
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("*\t%s\t*\n", inputs.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the amount of spaces dependent on the length of the longest input instead of just printing tabs on each side. You should also add a padding parameter in your printBox method to specify how many spaces to put on each side of the word.

Here is one possible solution that works pretty decently:

```
    int max = 0;
    int padding = 10;
    public void run() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> inputs = new ArrayList<>();
        String input;
        do {
            input = s.nextLine();
            inputs.add(input);
            max = Math.max(max, input.length());
        } while(!input.equals(""));
        printBox(inputs, padding);
    }

    public void printBox(ArrayList inputs, int padding) {
        printStars();
        // go to size - 1 because the last input is always ""
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size() - 1; i++) {
            int len = ((String)inputs.get(i)).length();
            int frontPad = (max + len)/2 + padding;
            // need to round or else sometimes the padding will be one too short
            int backPad = padding + (int)Math.round(((max - len)/2.0));
            System.out.printf("*%" + frontPad + "s%" + backPad + "s\n", inputs.get(i), "*");
        }
        printStars();
    }

    private void printStars() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= max + padding*2; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```